# Smoothing out a switching DC power supply

Tags: ripple

I have an audio device that is powered by a dual switching DC power supply (+15V/-15V). I am hearing a hum on the audio device and I believe it is from the switching power supply. Can someone recommend a simple circuit to add to the power supply output to help smooth out the ripples?

An earlier thread suggested a 0.1uf capacitor and a 10uf cap in parallel over the outputs. But since this is a +/- power supply I'm not sure about the polarity of the electrolytics, or if there are other factors to consider.

Comment: Not a good idea to use a cheap smps for powering audio amp.

Comment: Hum indicates mains frequency hum, not switch mode power supply noise. What power supply it is (make, model), is it a grounded supply, and connected to grounded outlet, or ungrounded? To what the system is connected to, is there a possibility of a ground loop?

Answer (score 2):

A typical switcher will be operating well over the 20KHz that we can hear.  (Humans in general, not me.)  Unless it's skipping cycles, it's probably not your problem.  If it is, the easiest and most reliable way to eliminate switching noise is to follow the switcher with an LDO to drop it another volt or so.

I'd look more at the AC connection and inputs to see if you're picking up the hum there.  Try shorting the inputs right at the connector--if the hum goes away, you have to start tracking it back from there.  If not, it's getting in somewhere else--at that point we have to know a lot of detail about the circuit and environment to help you.